# Curves on $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For curves in a projective plane there is a degree-genus formula.
Is there an analogue for curves on  $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$? More specially, is there a criterion (in terms of genus and degree) which tells us that certain curves cannot lie on  $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Each curve has a bidegree $(a,b)$. The canonical divisor has type $(-2,2)$. Using this and the adjunction formula you can write the genus $g$ in terms of $(a,b)$. If you want to compute the degree of the the curve under the Segre embedding note that the hyperplane divisor is $(1,1)$. (This is all assuming the curves are smooth.)

Comment: @Hoot: thanks, this is very helpful. please consider posting this an answer, if possible include $g$ in terms of $(a,b)$ so i can check my derivation. thanks!

Comment: By now I hope you have it figured out. Any curve is of type $(a,b)$ with $a,b\geq 0$ and any one of them is zero, it is easy to see what they are. If $a=0$, then the curve is irreducible only if $b=1$ and then we get a projective line (of degree 1 in the Segre). If $a>0, b>0$, the genus is $(a-1)(b-1)$ and degree is $a+b$.